# Java - Couchbase SDK 3.0 is throwing FeatureNotAvailableException exception

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I am running Spring boot with couchbase in OpenShift. My e1 and e2 environments are working fine. But when i move the code to e3 environment, i am getting below exception.

Can someone help me to resolve the issue?

Version :

> com.couchbase.client:java-client:3.0.6
> com.couchbase.client:core-io:2.0.7
> io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.3.5.RELEASE
> org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.3

1. During Startup we are getting timeout exception.

**Startup Exception:**

"application":{"name":"rf-data-service-a","namespace":"risk-fulfillment","version":null,"carId":600001102},"stacktrace":"java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 10000ms in 'source(MonoDefer)' (and no fallback has been configured)\n\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:289)\n\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.doTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:274)\n\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutTimeoutSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:396)\n\tat reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.onNext(StrictSubscriber.java:89)\n\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73)\n\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:117)\n\tat reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)\n\tat reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n...","level":"WARN","logId":"7c0283743d31d3f03de8175b0caf3c7000000000","message":"[com.couchbase.endpoint][EndpointConnectionFailedEvent][10s] Connect attempt 1 failed because of TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 10000ms in 'source(MonoDefer)' (and no fallback has been configured)

2. During API Access we are getting below exception

**N1QL Query Exception:**

Nov 09, 2020 11:27:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.couchbase.client.core.error.FeatureNotAvailableException: The cluster does not support cluster-level queries (only Couchbase Server 6.5 and later) and no bucket is open. If an older Couchbase Server version is used, at least one bucket needs to be opened to dispatch this query request!] with root cause
com.couchbase.client.core.error.FeatureNotAvailableException: The cluster does not support cluster-level queries (only Couchbase Server 6.5 and later) and no bucket is open. If an older Couchbase Server version is used, at least one bucket needs to be opened to dispatch this query request!
at com.couchbase.client.java.AsyncUtils.block(AsyncUtils.java:51)
at com.couchbase.client.java.Cluster.query(Cluster.java:393)
at com.aexp.risk.fulfill.core.sink.couchbase.ResilientCollection.fallbackQuery(ResilientCollection.java:363)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at io.github.resilience4j.fallback.FallbackMethod.invoke(FallbackMethod.java:212)
at io.github.resilience4j.fallback.FallbackMethod.fallback(FallbackMethod.java:174)
at io.github.resilience4j.fallback.DefaultFallbackDecorator.lambda$decorate$52452fd9$1(DefaultFallbackDecorator.java:40)
at io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configure.CircuitBreakerAspect.circuitBreakerAroundAdvice(CircuitBreakerAspect.java:118)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
at com.aexp.risk.fulfill.core.sink.couchbase.ResilientCollection$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$487c6753.query()
at com.aexp.risk.fulfill.rfdataservice.controller.JourneyController.getOrphanJourneys(JourneyController.java:94)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at io.opentracing.contrib.web.servlet.filter.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: The above exception was originally thrown by another thread at the following location.
at com.couchbase.client.core.error.FeatureNotAvailableException.clusterLevelQuery(FeatureNotAvailableException.java:41)
at com.couchbase.client.core.node.RoundRobinLocator.dispatch(RoundRobinLocator.java:92)
at com.couchbase.client.core.Core.send(Core.java:283)
at com.couchbase.client.core.Core.send(Core.java:259)
at com.couchbase.client.java.query.QueryAccessor.queryInternal(QueryAccessor.java:155)
at com.couchbase.client.java.query.QueryAccessor.queryAsync(QueryAccessor.java:120)
at com.couchbase.client.java.AsyncCluster.query(AsyncCluster.java:324)
... 71 more

Comment: Hi! This seems to be an issue with your couchbase version. Which one are you using?

Comment: I think it's a problem with Spring framework not respecting the port number defined in the properties file. Getting this now with CB6, I see in the logs it's trying to connect on port 11210